# Is it possible to have multi cam editing in Final Cut Express?

Tags: final-cut-express

Is is possible to do multi-camera editing in Final Cut Express like [this](http://www.kenstone.net/fcp_homepage/multicam_editing_martin.html)
 or [this](http://www.geniusdv.com/news_and_tutorials/2010/09/setting_up_multi_camera_edit_for_final_cut_pro.php)?

EDIT: I am using FCE 3.5 HD on Snow Leopard. Is that bad?

Comment: The last version of final cut express is the same as the last final cut pro (before X was released on the app store) so it is as capable as pro for multiple camera editing.

Comment: Is there a plugin for FCE 3.5 to do this?

Comment: I'm on 4.0.1 and it doesn't need a plug in. You might edit the question to reflect your specific version of Express. Are you still running 10.4 Tiger? (as FCE 3.5 isn't even supported on Leopard.)

Comment: @bmike I got FCE 4.0.1. How do you do multi-cam editing? And what do you mean by the last version of FCE is the same as the las version of FCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My general opinion it's never bad to keep your money in your pocket and keep using software that works.

The last version of final cut express is the same as the last final cut pro (before X was released on the app store) so it is as capable as pro for multiple camera editing.

The oldest Express version I have handy is 4.0.1 and it doesn't need any plug-ins to work for multi cam.

Comment: Thanks so much. I probably will do the same: keep FCE 3.5 and upgrade to FCE 4.0.1.

Comment: And the benefits of second hand software are many - problems are mostly known, you have many people with experience to show you the way. It often makes up for less vendor support, fewer patches and less modern features.

Comment: Second-hand software...meaning used software?